# How to start ui bootstrap carousel from middle of the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two angular bootstrap carousel on an array

```
$scope.slidesTwo = [
{image: 'http://placehold.it/250x200',smallImage:'http://placehold.it/300x200'},
{image: 'http://placehold.it/245x215',smallImage:'http://placehold.it/400x200'},
{image: 'http://placehold.it/240x210',smallImage:'http://placehold.it/300x300'}
  ];
```

I would like two start the first carousel from index 1 and second carousel from index 0. Any pointers on how to achieve it?

Here is link to http://plnkr.co/edit/bKt3QZlGO3aEpXlejgpp?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify custom filter function:

controller:

```
  $scope.filterFn = function(value, index) {
    return index !== 0;
  }
```

html

```
<slide ng-repeat="slide in slidesTwo | filter : filterFn" active="slide.active">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bAIGpnS9ssBmYfIEFY8J?p=preview

note: index in filter function is available only in angular 1.3.x, if you have no possibility to update angular version, you have to find index by value in filter function